# .htaccess RewriteRule to redirect any blog page with url parameter to home page

Tags: .htaccess, query-string, redirect, http-status-code-301

For example, I want to redirect Any page with the parameter **?blog** to the home page of my new site

http://www.example.co.uk/default.aspx?blog=blogs/archive/2015/12/14/key.for.less.aspx

...and redirect it to:

http://www.example.co.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to write the below rule in `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^blog=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^default.aspx$ /? [R=301,L]
```